# Firebase Firestore: Cannot call useEmulator() after instance has already been initialized

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I am using Firebase [Emulator Suite](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_firestore) to test my Firebase Cloud Functions before deploying them into production.

Exploring [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4779992/9636037) approach to trigger the callable firebase cloud functions from my Andriod device.

My App is crashing when I run it.

***Error:***

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call useEmulator() after instance has already been initialized.

Source of the error - **FirebaseFirestore.java**:

```
/**
   * Modifies this FirebaseDatabase instance to communicate with the Cloud Firestore emulator.
   *
   * <p>Note: Call this method before using the instance to do any database operations.
   *
   * @param host the emulator host (for example, 10.0.2.2)
   * @param port the emulator port (for example, 8080)
   */
  public void useEmulator(@NonNull String host, int port) {
    if (this.client != null) {
      throw new IllegalStateException(
          "Cannot call useEmulator() after instance has already been initialized.");
    }

    this.emulatorSettings = new EmulatedServiceSettings(host, port);
    this.settings = mergeEmulatorSettings(this.settings, this.emulatorSettings);
  }
```

Firestore is injected using the following method: (Using Hilt in my project)

```
@Provides
fun provideFirebaseFirestore(): FirebaseFirestore {

    val firebaseFirestoreSettings = FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
    firebaseFirestoreSettings.isPersistenceEnabled = false

    val firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    firestore.useEmulator("192.168.1.102", 8080)
    firestore.firestoreSettings = firebaseFirestoreSettings.build()

    return firestore
}
```

My doubt is `useEmulator()` in `FirebaseFirestore.java` is not a static method.
How can I call it before creating an instance of Firebase Firestore?

Comment: Do you have any other code anywhere else in your app that calls `FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()`?

Comment: @DougStevenson, Nope, the dependency is inside `@Module
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
class FirebaseModule {....}`

Comment: Single module app at the moment.

Comment: If you have a stripped down, absolutely minimal application that generates this error with only the code you have here, I suggest filing a bug report with an explanation how to reproduce it.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem and the way I solved it wrap the `firestore.useEmulator("192.168.1.102", 8080)` in a try catch block like this

```
    try {
            firestore.useEmulator("192.168.1.102", 8080)
        } catch (e: IllegalStateException) {

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

That could be because the Firebase state is kept between tests. The useEmulator is then called twice against the same firebase app instance, raising the error. At least, that was what happened to me during tests.

The approach to check a nested "host" property in the firestore instance -- described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66933212/7024301) -- was what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Adding @Singleton to the function `provideFirebaseFirestore()` solved the issue for me, as it makes sure the class only gets instantiated once.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with `com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.0.0`

As the documentation of `useEmulator()` method says:

> Note: Call this method before using the instance to do any database operations.

I was calling these method before very first use during dependency injection, that was causing the issue.

Anyway **SOLVED** by lifting those call to `MainActivity`s `onCreate` method as:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        if (USE_EMULATOR) {
            Firebase.auth.useEmulator(HOST, AUTH_PORT)
            Firebase.firestore.useEmulator(HOST, FIRESTORE_PORT)
        }
        setContent { MainContent() }
    }
}
```