# Firebase emulators with Next.js

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I'm trying to setup Firebase's V9 emulators with Next.js without any luck. I'm always getting this error,
[image]

My firebase version is, `9.1.1`.

My Firebase setup looks like this:

```js
import { initializeApp, FirebaseApp } from "firebase/app";
import { initializeApp, FirebaseApp } from "firebase/app";
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import { getAuth, connectAuthEmulator, Auth } from "firebase/auth";
import {
  getFirestore,
  connectFirestoreEmulator,
  Firestore,
} from "firebase/firestore";
import {
  getStorage,
  connectStorageEmulator,
  FirebaseStorage,
} from "firebase/storage";
import {
  getDatabase,
  connectDatabaseEmulator,
  Database,
} from "firebase/database";

let firebaseApp: FirebaseApp;
let auth: Auth;
let firestore: Firestore;
let storage: FirebaseStorage;
let db: Database;

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebaseApp = initializeApp(clientCredentials);
  auth = getAuth(firebaseApp);
  firestore = getFirestore(firebaseApp);
  storage = getStorage(firebaseApp);
  db = getDatabase(firebaseApp);
}

if (IS_DEV) {
  connectFirestoreEmulator(firestore, "localhost", 8080);
  connectAuthEmulator(auth, "http://localhost:9099", { disableWarnings: true });
  connectDatabaseEmulator(db, "localhost", 9000);
  connectStorageEmulator(storage, "localhost", 9199);
}

export { firebaseApp, auth, firestore, storage, db }
```

I've made sure there's no calling of my firestore object. As soon as Next.js starts up, I get that error.

Comment: Can you share all the imports as well and which version are you using ? I can only see firebase import at top.

Comment: @Dharmaraj Yes. I update the question

Comment: Hi there! It looks like xxxuseEmulator is being called multiple times for the same browser instance. I suggest you to check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65066963/firebase-firestore-emulator-error-host-has-been-set-in-both-settings-and-usee) in which the same issue is discussed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase Firestore emulator error \`Host has been set in both settings() and useEmulator(), emulator host will be used\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65066963/firebase-firestore-emulator-error-host-has-been-set-in-both-settings-and-usee)

Comment: @MartinNordström has the provided solution fixed your problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening due to global namespace values and the NextJs runtime.

You can fix this as follows:

```js
const EMULATORS_STARTED = 'EMULATORS_STARTED';
function startEmulators() {
  if (!global[EMULATORS_STARTED]) {
    global[EMULATORS_STARTED] = true;
    connectFunctionsEmulator(functions, 'localhost', 5001);
    connectFirestoreEmulator(db, 'localhost', 8080);
    connectAuthEmulator(auth, "http://localhost:9099", { disableWarnings: true });
    connectDatabaseEmulator(db, "localhost", 9000);
    connectStorageEmulator(storage, 'localhost', 9199);
  }
}
```

Firebase adds a global namespace of 'EMULATORS_STARTED' once it has started and NextJs attempts to run that code multiple times. This script will prevent you from attempting to connect to the emulators more than once.

Comment: where should we place the start emulators function?

Comment: its up to you. Somewhere that initiates before any code that requires firebase.
I usually put it in a lib/firebase.tsx