# Firestore keeps trying to setup emulators when it's already running in Next.js app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, next.js, firebase-tools

Has anyone ran into troubles with firebase and its emulators? I keep getting the following error on hot reload.

> **FirebaseError: Firestore has already been started and its settings can no longer be changed. You can only modify settings before calling
> any other methods on a Firestore object.**

Initialisation:

```
// Initialize Firebase
const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

let mode = "emulate";

const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp);
const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp);
const storage = getStorage(firebaseApp);
const functions = getFunctions(firebaseApp);

if (mode === "emulate") {
  connectAuthEmulator(auth, "http://localhost:9099");
  connectFirestoreEmulator(db, "localhost", 8080);
  connectStorageEmulator(storage, "localhost", 9199);
  connectFunctionsEmulator(functions, "localhost", 5001);
}

export { firebaseApp, db, auth, storage, functions };
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase Firestore emulator error \`Host has been set in both settings() and useEmulator(), emulator host will be used\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65066963/firebase-firestore-emulator-error-host-has-been-set-in-both-settings-and-usee)

Answer (score 2):

I will add the solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65066963/firebase-firestore-emulator-error-host-has-been-set-in-both-settings-and-usee) here as it worked for me.

#### Solution

```js
    const EMULATORS_STARTED = 'EMULATORS_STARTED';
    function startEmulators() {
      if (!global[EMULATORS_STARTED]) {
        global[EMULATORS_STARTED] = true;
        firebase.firestore().useEmulator('localhost', <your_port>);
        firebase.auth().useEmulator('http://localhost:<your_port>/');
      }
    }
    
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
      startEmulators();
    }
```

*Note*- If you are using Firebase V9:

```js
const EMULATORS_STARTED = 'EMULATORS_STARTED';
function startEmulators() {
  if (!global[EMULATORS_STARTED]) {
    global[EMULATORS_STARTED] = true;
    connectFunctionsEmulator(functions, 'localhost', <your_port>);

    connectFirestoreEmulator(db, 'localhost', <your_port>);
  }
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  startEmulators();
}
```

#### Reason:

The reason this needs to be done is that NextJS is trying to run the connect to the emulators many times over. This prevents emulators from connecting more than once.

Answer (score 1):

Seems `useEmulator` is called multiple times from the same browser instance. My suggestion is check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65066963/firebase-firestore-emulator-error-host-has-been-set-in-both-settings-and-usee) in which the similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem and the following did the trick for me.

```
import { getApps } from 'firebase/app';

if (getApps().length === 0) {
   connectAuthEmulator(auth, "http://localhost:9099");
   connectFirestoreEmulator(db, "localhost", 8080);
   connectStorageEmulator(storage, "localhost", 9199);
   connectFunctionsEmulator(functions, "localhost", 5001);  
}
```