# "@firebase/firestore: Firestore (8.10.0): Host has been set in both settings() and useEmulator(), emulator host will be used" on Hot Refresh

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web

I am trying to build a flutter web app. I using the Firebase emulator to test the app. So when I Hot Refresh, I get the error in the title along with:

`FirebaseError: Firestore has already been started and its settings can no longer be changed. You can only modify settings before calling any other methods on a Firestore object.`

My `main()`:

```dart
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

  String host = 'localhost';

  if (isEmulator) {
    if (!kIsWeb) {
      host = Platform.isAndroid ? '10.0.2.2' : host;
    }

    await FirebaseAuth.instance.useAuthEmulator(host, 9099);

    try {
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.useFirestoreEmulator(host, 8080);
    } on Exception catch(e){
      debugPrint('continue');
    }

    await fb_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance.useStorageEmulator(host, 9199);
    //FirebaseFunctions.instance.useFunctionsEmulator(host, 5001);

  }

  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

I also wrapped `useFirestoreEmulator()` in a try-catch. But the dart2js transformation does not consider the `FirebaseError` in Javascript as an exception. So I do not have a way to divert it.

my flutter doctor:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1415], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 2.8.0 at C:\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision cf44000065 (2 weeks ago), 2021-12-08 14:06:50 -0800
    • Engine revision 40a99c5951
    • Dart version 2.15.0

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\muddi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)

[√] VS Code (version 1.63.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\muddi\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.29.0

[√] Connected device (2 available)
    • Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 96.0.4664.110
    • Edge (web)   • edge   • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 96.0.1054.62

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 1):

Reviewing for information related to the error message you are getting, I found a solution that is to [call useEmulator after enablePersistence](https://github.com/nuxt-community/firebase-module/commit/bc16b45a712e3c6400f7c9f8fa1af4233679b46c) to fix the "Firestore has already been started" issue.

Now, you will need to make sure that all emulators have started before making a request.
I also found a similar question in [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65066963/firebase-firestore-emulator-error-host-has-been-set-in-both-settings-and-usee) that contains two answers with a solution that would probably help with the error message, one solution is also using a `Hot Refresh`.

Comment: I had already looked at those solutions. Unfortunately, issue is known bug in the `cloud_firebase` package for Flutter.

Thank you for your help either way.